# compare validaiton in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two register form in same page using same model.Both form have same fields like following,

> 1.username
>   2.password
>   3.repeatPassword

Form 1 is working fine, but form 2 compare validation not working correctly. It always return error message when  i enter repeatPassword is correctly then also it return error message. I think problem is field id because when i enter form1 password field and form2 repeatPassword field as same at the time it's working.

**Model rule:**

```
[['repeatPassword'], 'required','message' => 'Please re-enter the Password','on' => ['register']],
[['repeatPassword'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message' =>'Please re-enter the password.This is to check that you have not mistyped any characters '],
```

**UPDATE**

View

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'student-register-form',
    'action'=>['user/student-register'],
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-12\">{input}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-sm-5 control-label'],
    ],  
]); ?>  
<?= $form->errorSummary($user, ['header' => '']); ?>
<?= $form->field($user, 'username')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Username'],['style'=>'text-indent:20px;'])->label(false)?> 
<?= $form->field($user, 'password')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'Password'])->label(false) ?>   
<?= $form->field($user, 'repeatPassword')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'ConfirmPassword'])->label(false) ?>
<?= $form->field($user, 'acceptTerms')->checkBox()->label("I agree with the <a href='#'>Terms & Conditions<a/>") ?>
<?= $form->field($user, 'role')->hiddenInput(['value'=>1]);?> 
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-12 register-button mrgT-15">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('user', 'Register'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit-register']) ?>             
    </div>
</div>
```

This is form1 and form2 also same setup, only formid,hidden input value and form action is different.And controller actions also same code render form and process the post request.

**Note**:Both forms are render in main layout.

Comment: show your view and controller code

Comment: thank u response back, please see my updated question

Comment: may be you are you are using same variable for both form. show you controller code and full code on view file

Comment: yes i am using same model variable in both form, and problem is on field id

Comment: you need to use two different variable for different form

Comment: validation is made by javascript and your fields have same id because of model name so just first will be validated

Comment: just try to change variable name user1 for form1 and user2 for form2 and see if it works